# Cakephp 3.4 plugin/theme view class not found

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to load a view class from my theme but it's throwing an error not found.  I'm trying to load custom configs for Paginator and Form from my theme. The theme loads fine and all assets for theme work just can't get the view class to load. Below is the file listings and relevant files.

Theme name: **Material**

Files:

- **config/bootstrap.php**
- **src/Controller/AppController.php**
- **plugins/Material/src/View/MaterialView.php**
- **plugins/Material/config/paginator-templates.php**
- **plugins/Material/config/form-templates.php**

**bootstrap.php**

```
Plugin::load('Material');
```

**AppController.php**

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setTheme('Material');
    $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('Material.Material');
}
```

**MaterialView.php**

```
namespace Material\View;

use Cake\View\View;

class MaterialView extends View
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadHelper('Paginator', ['templates' => 'paginator-templates']);
        $this->loadHelper('Form', ['templates' => 'form-templates']);
    }
}
```

Additional Information:

Error Message: **View class "Material.Material" is missing.**  There are no file creation hints shown.

Stack Trace:

```
2017-09-17 15:34:17 Error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingViewException] 

View class "Material.Material" is missing.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'Material.Material',
)
Request URL: /register
Referer URL: http://localhost/
Stack Trace:
#0 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/ViewVarsTrait.php(118): Cake\View\ViewBuilder->build(Array, Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Event\EventManager))
#1 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(622): Cake\Controller\Controller->createView()
#2 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(125): Cake\Controller\Controller->render()
#3 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(93): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\CryptoUsersController))
#4 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(78): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#5 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#6 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(59): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#7 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#8 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#9 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#10 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(92): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#11 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#12 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/src/Middleware/DebugKitMiddleware.php(52): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#13 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): DebugKit\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#14 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#15 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(80): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#16 /mnt/internal-storage/Web Development/crypto/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#17 {main}
```

What am I missing here?  I feel like it's probably something obvious but going right over my head.

Comment: Please post the exact error message that you receive (including the possible file creation hints shown on the error page), and the full stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion). Also have you added the plugin path to your composer configuration, and re-dumped the autoloader?

Comment: Updated post with requested info.  I did not re-dump autoloader but the plugin path is in the composer config

Comment: Then please re-dump the autoloader (`composer dump-autoload`), and do a quick test like `debug(class_exists(\Material\View\MaterialView::class))` to check whether autoloading is working.

Comment: Ran dump-autoload.  debug(class_exists(\Material\View\MaterialView::class)) returns false

Comment: I did find that if I use the deprecated method 'className' instead of 'setClassName' it gives me a file creation hint and it seems to be looking for a file named 'Material.Material' and not in the plugin folder.  Error: Create the class Material.Material below in file: src/View/Material.Material.php

Comment: `className()` vs `setClassName()` shouldn't make any difference. I'd suggest to start with exploring why autoloading seems to be not working (make sure you've used the correct paths in your composer config, ensure that the files really exist, that their case is correct, and that they are readable (permissions, etc)).

Comment: Well the theme layout files all work and the assets load which makes me think the permissions are correct.

Comment: Ok.  I think I was missing the composer.json file.  I baked the plugin instead of making the folders manually and everything seems to be working.  I never had a composer.json file in the theme folder which is created when you bake.  Will use bake from now on.